# Drag & Drop with right mouse button

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to DnD with right mouse button in Java Swing components? I cannot figure it out how to do that. I have my current DnD enabled on `JTable` like that:

```
setDragEnabled(true);
setDropMode(DropMode.USE_SELECTION);
setTransferHandler(new FilesDragAndDropHandler());
```

I would like to have an ability to Dnd with right mouse button too, because when the right mouse button is released, I planned to show a popup with items `Copy` and `Move`. Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: Just note that it is physically harder to drag something, while holding the right button.

Comment: Kind of, maybe, if you're prepared to do all the work yourself and it will only work from within the context of your program

Comment: A better idea would be to use a combination of left mouse drag and some key, like shift, ctrl or alt

Comment: @MadProgrammer, ok but where should I check if some key is pressed? Is it in the `TransferHandler`?

Comment: [`TransferHandler#exportAsDrag`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportAsDrag(javax.swing.JComponent,%20java.awt.event.InputEvent,%20int))